# Vertically center a tikzpicture with respect to the page (title page)

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the MWE below, I have to manually offset my tikzpicture to align it vertically center with respect to the page. Is there a way that I can have it do this automatically? If the length of the tikzpicture changes, so does the positioning.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\def\titlineoffset{1.5}
\def\titlineabove{1.5}
\def\titlinebelow{3}

\newcounter{lastitlenode}\setcounter{lastitlenode}{1}   %
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtitele}{ O{1.0} O{\normalfont} D(){} m }{%  TODO figure out how to get away without needing node names in (), it throws an error
  \stepcounter{lastitlenode}
  \node[font={#2}, below=#1 of lastnode.south west, anchor=north west] (\IfValueTF{#3}{#3}{lastnode\thelastitlenode}) {#4};
  \coordinate (lastnode) at (\IfValueTF{#3}{#3}{lastnode\thelastitlenode}.south west);
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setlastnode}{m}{%
  \coordinate (lastnode) at (#1.south west);
}



\def\maketitle{\begin{titlepage}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  shift={($(current page.west)+(5.8, 7.0)$)}, anchor=west,  % <-------- RIGHT HERE. If 
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  I have to manually off-set the y-shift \
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% I want it such that if I change the 7.0 to zero, the picture is centered vertically
  node distance=1cm,
  every node/.style={anchor=west,inner sep=0pt,align=left},]
  \node[font={\LARGE\bfseries}] (title) {title\\title\\}; \setlastnode{title}
  \addtitele[1][\itshape](sub){subtitle\\sub\\sub}
  \addtitele[0.5][\itshape\bfseries](deg){Master of Science}
  \addtitele[0.5][\itshape](by){by}
  \addtitele[1][\Large\bfseries](auth){author}
  \addtitele[1.5](publi){publishers}
  \addtitele[2.5](date){date}
  \draw ($(title.north west)+(-\titlineoffset,\titlineabove)$) |- ($(lastnode.south west)+(-\titlineoffset,-\titlinebelow)$);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{titlepage}%
\clearpage
}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Hello world}

\end{document}
```

I want the center of the tikzpicture to be centered with the page as my reference, and allow a y-shift from there if needed.

[image]

Comment: Can't you just place it centred on `current page.center`? You don't really need tikz either.

Comment: No because the length of my titles might vary a bit which will throw it off. I want a fixed distance from the left side of page (5.8cm in this example),  it I want the picture to be vertical centered with respect to the west anchor point of the page, and then impart some y-offset from that reference.

Comment: And I know I don't need tikz for this, but there are many aspects of using it that will make this easier for me to extend later on.